# Selenium pick 1st and last active date from date picker

Tags: java, selenium

I am trying to find the 1st and last active date. In the image below, you can see the 1st active day is June 02. The last active day will be June 01 2022

[image]

I want to get the 1st active date which is June02,2021 and the last active date

This code I have prints 2021-5-3, It is not printing 2021-6-3

```
List<WebElement> columns = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//td[not(@class=' ui-datepicker-other-month ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled') and not(@class=' ui-datepicker-week-end ui-datepicker-other-month ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled') and not(@class=' ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled ')]"));
    ArrayList<String> yearList= new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> monthList= new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> dateList= new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=1;i<columns.size();i++){
        yearList.add(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[@class=\" \"]")).getAttribute("data-year"));
        monthList.add(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[@class=\" \"]")).getAttribute("data-month"));
        dateList.add(driver.findElements(By.xpath("//td[@data-handler=\"selectDay\"]/..//a[@href]")).get(i).getText());
        /*System.out.println(driver.findElements(By.xpath("//td[@data-handler=\"selectDay\"]/..//a[@href]")).get(i).getText() + "-"+
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[@class=\" \"]")).getAttribute("data-month") + "-"
        + driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[@class=\" \"]")).getAttribute("data-year"));*/

    }
    System.out.println("1st Active Date " + yearList.get(0) +"-"+monthList.get(0)+"-"+dateList.get(0));
```

I am also trying to click the Next > symbol till I can get the last active date. I tried the code below but it fails with element not found exception

```
 if ((driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='ui-datepicker-next ui-corner-all' and @title='Next']")).isDisplayed())) {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@title='Next']")).click();
        while(!(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='ui-datepicker-next ui-corner-all ui-state-disabled' and @title='Next']")).isDisplayed()) ){
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@title='Next']")).click();
      }
        /*if ((driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='ui-datepicker-next ui-corner-all ui-state-disabled' and @title='Next']")).isDisplayed())) {
            break;
        }*/
    }
```

[image]

[image]

```
<a class="ui-datepicker-next ui-corner-all" data-handler="next" data-event="click" title="Next"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-triangle-e">Next</span></a>
```

2
1

```
<div id="ui-datepicker-div" class="ui-datepicker ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all" style="position: absolute; top: 222.562px; left: 243.688px; z-index: 1;"><div class="ui-datepicker-header ui-widget-header ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all"><a class="ui-datepicker-prev ui-corner-all ui-state-disabled" title="Prev"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-triangle-w">Prev</span></a><a class="ui-datepicker-next ui-corner-all" data-handler="next" data-event="click" title="Next"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-triangle-e">Next</span></a><div class="ui-datepicker-title"><span class="ui-datepicker-month">June</span>&nbsp;<span class="ui-datepicker-year">2021</span></div></div><table class="ui-datepicker-calendar"><thead><tr><th scope="col" class="ui-datepicker-week-end"><span title="Sunday">Su</span></th><th scope="col"><span title="Monday">Mo</span></th><th scope="col"><span title="Tuesday">Tu</span></th><th scope="col"><span title="Wednesday">We</span></th><th scope="col"><span title="Thursday">Th</span></th><th scope="col"><span title="Friday">Fr</span></th><th scope="col" class="ui-datepicker-week-end"><span title="Saturday">Sa</span></th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end ui-datepicker-other-month ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled">&nbsp;</td><td class=" ui-datepicker-other-month ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled">&nbsp;</td><td class=" ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled "><span class="ui-state-default">1</span></td><td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="5" data-year="2021"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">2</a></td><td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="5" data-year="2021"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">3</a></td><td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="5" data-year="2021"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">4</a></td><td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="5" data-year="2021"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">5</a></td></tr><tr><td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="5" data-year="2021"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">6</a></td><td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="5" data-year="2021"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">7</a></td><td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="5" data-year="2021"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">8</a></td><td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="5" data-year="2021"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">9</a></td><td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="5" data-year="2021"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">10</a></td><td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="5" data-year="2021"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">11</a></td><td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end  ui-datepicker-today" data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="5" data-year="2021"><a class="ui-state-default ui-state-highlight" href="#">12</a></td></tr><tr><td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="5" data-year="2021"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">13</a></td><td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="5" data-year="2021"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">14</a></td><td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="5" data-year="2021"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">15</a></td><td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="5" data-year="2021"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">16</a></td><td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="5" data-year="2021"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">17</a></td><td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="5" data-year="2021"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">18</a></td><td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="5" data-year="2021"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">19</a></td></tr><tr><td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="5" data-year="2021"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">20</a></td><td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="5" data-year="2021"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">21</a></td><td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="5" data-year="2021"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">22</a></td><td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="5" data-year="2021"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">23</a></td><td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="5" data-year="2021"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">24</a></td><td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="5" data-year="2021"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">25</a></td><td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="5" data-year="2021"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">26</a></td></tr><tr><td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="5" data-year="2021"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">27</a></td><td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="5" data-year="2021"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">28</a></td><td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="5" data-year="2021"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">29</a></td><td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="5" data-year="2021"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">30</a></td><td class=" ui-datepicker-other-month ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled">&nbsp;</td><td class=" ui-datepicker-other-month ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled">&nbsp;</td><td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end ui-datepicker-other-month ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled">&nbsp;</td></tr></tbody></table></div>
```

Thanks in advance for your time and help.

Comment: Do you want to find the last active date on current month, or you'll ask selenium to keep hitting next until there is no active date?

Comment: We need to see your full HTML to solve this. Please don't post pictures; they're very hard to read, impossible to copy, and don't show all the necessary info anyway.

Comment: @prakasht keep hitting next till I get July01 2022 Thanks.

Comment: @C.Peck long code I tried to put some HTML code in the bottom. Thanks

Comment: That HTML isn't helpful. do you have a link to the site?

Answer (score 1):

It can be done with the help of `last()` method in xpath.
You need to follow the following logic:

1. Find an xpath to match with all **active** dates. 
    `String activeDatesXpath = "find_this_xpath"; // You can fill this xpath as you have the html.`
2. First get the first active date using: 
    `WebElement firstDate = driver.findElement(By.xpath(activeDatesXpath + "[0]"))`
3. Now to find the last active date, run a loop until you hit `NoSuchElementException`, and save the last active date on each page

```
WebElement lastDate = driver.findElement(By.xpath(activeDatesXpath + "[last()]");
while(true) {
       try {
           // Click Next
           driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@title='Next']")).click();
           // Update the lastDate element
           lastDate = driver.findElement(By.xpath(activeDatesXpath + "[last()]");
       } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
           break;
       }
}
```

You should also put a max pages limit so that if the active dates don't end then your code isn't stuck in an infinite loop.